How to implement k6 webcrypto encryption same way as PHP openssl_encrypt function
I got a code to encrypt some text in PHP, it looks like this:
$key = '1234aaaff80b56233525ac2355ac3456'; // something like this
$utf16Content = \mb_convert_encoding('Some text', 'UTF-16LE');
$cipher = 'aes-256-gcm';
$nonceLength = \openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$nonce = \openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($nonceLength);

$encryptedContent = \openssl_encrypt($utf16Content, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $nonce, $tag);

echo 'Nonce: '.\base64_encode($nonce);
echo 'Auth Tag: '.\base64_encode($tag); 
echo 'Content: '.$encryptedContent; 


How could I implement the same behavior in JS webcrypto? (I need that for the k6 tests) I found a documentation but it isn't clear for me.
For now I have code like this but I cannot decrypt that successfully so I guess something isn't right.
const rawKey = Uint8Array.from(new String('1234aaaff80b56233525ac2355ac3456'), (x) => x.charCodeAt(0));

const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
     'raw',
     rawKey,
     { name: 'AES-GCM', length: 256 },
     false,
     ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
);
const nonce = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));

const encrypted = await crypto.subtle.encrypt({
       name: 'AES-GCM',
       iv: nonce,
       tagLength: 128,
    },
    key,
    stringToArrayBuffer('Some text')
);

const sentData = {};
sentData.content = b64encode(encrypted);
sentData.nonce = b64encode(nonce);
sentData.authTag = b64encode(GetTag(encrypted, 128));


function stringToArrayBuffer(str) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length * 2);
    const bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}

function GetTag(encrypted, tagLength) {
    if (tagLength === void 0) tagLength = 128;
    return encrypted.slice(encrypted.byteLength - ((tagLength + 7) >> 3))
}

I think the main problem is creating correct authTag and changing String rawKey to ArrayBuffer.
BTW decription code looks like this (PHP):
// $content, $nonce, $authenticationTag - from PHP encription script output 
$content = \base64_decode($content, true);
$nonce = \base64_decode($nonce, true);
$authenticationTag = \base64_decode($authenticationTag, true);
        
$result = \openssl_decrypt(
    $content,
    'aes-256-gcm',
    '1234aaaff80b56233525ac2355ac3456',
    \OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    $nonce,
    $authenticationTag
);


...I cannot decrypt that successfully so I guess something isn't right... Post your decryption code so that a repro is possible.

The PHP codes do not match. Where is the encoding of tag and IV in the encryption part, where is the decoding from UTF-16LE to the start encoding? Though the latter is also unclear, possibly UTF-8. It makes little sense to look for a solution if part of the information needed has to be guessed, post a full MCVE.

At least one bug seems to be the wrong handling of the authentication tag in the WebCrypto code. The tag is generally created automatically during encryption. WebCrypto appends it to the ciphertext (so it corresponds to the last 16 bytes of encrypted). Both parts must be separated in the PHP code, as PHP/openssl processes the ciphertext and tag individually. In addition, the tag is not identical to the AAD (additionalData). No AADs are used in the PHP code, so none should be used in the WebCrypto code (the line additionalData: authTag should therefore be removed).

You right about that wrong additionalData: authTag, I got function GetTag  from very similar question. So for now I think that nonce (iv) and authTag at least look correct but I'm not sure about encrypted variable whether it should be processed in some way in that JS code.

@Topaco Hey man Your advice "processes the ciphertext and tag individually" makes me wonder so I've started to looking at some other question on StackOverflow and I found this and the code const [value, auth_tag] = [encrypted.slice(0, encrypted.byteLength - 16), encrypted.slice(encrypted.byteLength - 16),]; was the answer for my problem. So I really thank you for that!

For the record: I figured out how I can get authTag from encrypted text using k6/experimental/webcrypto
import { crypto } from 'k6/experimental/webcrypto';

const encrypted = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
{
        name: 'AES-GCM',
        iv: nonce,
        tagLength: 128,
    },
    key,
    plaintext
);

const [ value, authTag] = [
    encrypted.slice(0, encrypted.byteLength - 16),
    encrypted.slice(encrypted.byteLength - 16),
];

